# CSS to get perfect circle around number using border-radius

Tags: css

I'm trying to achieve this: http://puu.sh/iQNoG/4ea224e4ad.png

and here's [my code:](http://jsfiddle.net/27a7ucd9/1/)

```
<div class="credit-callout">
<ul>
    <li>C M E</li>
    <li class="credit-number">19.5</li>
    <li>CREDITS</li>
</ul>
```

I suspect that my issue might be that I'm using line-items but i wasn't able to get them on 1 line without going this route.

Answer (score 3):

Because the number is wide you will need the padding top & bottom to be larger than left & right to get a perfect circle

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/qtLx6cct/

**Css**

```
.credit-number {
padding-top:18px;
padding-bottom:18px;
padding-left:5px;
padding-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/27a7ucd9/1

```
 .credit-callout li.credit-number { padding: 21px 15px;}
```

Your number is larger from left and right side, that's why you not getting perfect circle... just user padding in number class.

Comment: if you change 19.5 to 1, in example, perfect circle fails.